# ionic Cordova is not available

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, calendar, cordova-plugins

i am using ionic native calendar in ionic 3.9.2 ,i have already installed and included the module in the app module , here is the code where i am calling the calendar :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Calendar } from '@ionic-native/calendar';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-evenements',
  templateUrl: 'evenements.html',
})
export class EvenementsPage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,private calendar: Calendar) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad EvenementsPage');
    this.calendar.createCalendar('MyCalendar').then(
      (msg) => { console.log(msg); },
      (err) => { console.log(err); }
    );
  }

}
```

the page is empty and  the calendar is not being displayed and this is my console log :

```
Native: tried calling Calendar.createCalendar, but Cordova is not available. Make sure to include cordova.js or run in a device/simulator
util.js (66,1)

cordova_not_available
```

Notice : i am running the app on a web browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can build it on the browser using the command:
ionic cordova run browser

some of the plugins are compatible with browsers
you can check here to see the compatibility of each plugin in the left-hand side menu:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native

Answer (score 3):

Cordova is only included when you are running natively on a device, not when serving development version to a browser. Therefore cannot be used when testing in the browser. Of course, this means that Cordova-based plugins won't work either. This is a limitation of testing in the browser.

To test all the features, you must test it on an emulator or on a real target device.

That's being said, since Cordova and some of its plugins support browsers, your browser can become a target device if you build for browser platform.

`ionic cordova platform add browser`

`ionic cordova run browser`

This will build and run your project in a browser. Development friend live reload / source maps / fast builds may not be available with this option. A quick googleing shows a few way to improve but this is still not recommended and fully supported. Ionic team recommends using the platform api to detect and handle browsers and devices separately in your code.